# multi processing in python getting stuck in a while True loop

Tags: python, multithreading

for some reason the code does not get to the main function. I am using cloud9 to run the code so that might be the issue.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Value
import time

def main():
    print "main function"

def market_price_thread():
    while True:
        market_price()
        time.sleep(5)


def market_price():
    #do something
    print "end"



def start_threads():

    thread = Process(target=market_price_thread())
    thread.start()

    time.sleep(5)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_threads()
    main() #does not seem to get to this
```

Answer (score 1):

You've asked Python to call `market_price_thread`:

```
thread = Process(target=market_price_thread())
```

and then use whatever it returns, as the `target` value.  So, before calling `Process`, we'll have to wait for `market_price_thread` to return.  What value does it return, and when?

(Compare with `Process(target=market_price_thread)`, which does *not* call `market_price_thread` yet, but rather, passes the function to `Process` so that `Process` can call it.)

Comment: Basically the thread that I am calling will keep changeing a global variable and it will never return.

Comment: My question is meant to make you think about the problem (and the answer is in the last paragraph).